# Connect to an Access DB from Java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

How to connect to an access db from java?

I have:

- fully installed java sdk-jdk & jre
- and apache derby database.
- My access is 2007 version.
- os windows 7.

Comment: I tried to process sql statements from cmd to ms access-i couldnt.

Comment: i tried to do something within the odbc manager of control panel\administrative tools.i couldnt do any thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
public class myConnection 
{

// JDBC driver name and database URL
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
private static final String DATABASE_URL ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=.\\database.accdb";

// declare Connection for accessing and querying database
private Connection connection;


// constructor connects to database
public myConnection () 
{ 
    try 
    {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);

    } 

    catch (SQLException sqlException)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlException.getMessage(),
                "Database Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(1);
    }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, classNotFound.getMessage(),
                "Driver Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void closeConnection()
{
    try 
    {
        connection.close();
    }

    catch (SQLException sqlException)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlException.getMessage(),
                "Database Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public Connection getConnection()
{
    return connection;
}
```

}